# How to color DC js bubble chart based on column value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, dc.js, bubble-chart

I am fairly new to dc js and have been trying to set up a bubble chart in DC js with custom color coding but have not had the luck so far. The bubble chart works fine with the "d3.scale.category20()" color scale but throws a "_colors.range is not a function" error if I try to give it a custom coloring scale.

I want to give a different color based on the range of the "sic" variable. For example : if the value is between 0 and 1000, it should be red, 1000-2000, it should be blue and so on.

I tried to create a d3 ordinal scale and specify the domain and range for corresponding values, then in the color accessor function, I tried to return the domain value based on the value of the variable(d.key in this case), however when I check the code on the browser, I get a "_colors.range is not a function" TypeError

Here's the complete dc js and crossfilter js code

```
var industryChart = dc.bubbleChart("#industry-chart");


// load data from a csv file
d3.csv("df_20topics_5types.csv", function (data) {

data.forEach(function(d) { 
d.cik=+d.cik;
d.year = +d.year;
d.sic = +d.sic;
d.type_count = +d.type_count;
d.sic2 =+d.sic2;
d.sic3 = +d.sic3;
d.maxtopic = d.maxtopic;
d.maxweight = +d.maxweight;
d.topic0 = +d.topic0;
d.topic1 = +d.topic1;
//d.month = +d.month;
//console.log(d.topic0)
});


var facts = crossfilter(data);
var all = facts.groupAll();

var sicValueOrig = facts.dimension(function (d) {
// console.log(d.sic);
return d.sic;  
// add the SIC dimension

});
var sicValueGroupCountOrig = sicValueOrig.group()
 .reduceSum(function(d) { return d.type_count; });  


var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["000","1000","2000",""])
        .range(["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"]);

industryChart.width(990)
                .height(280)
                .x(d3.scale.pow(2))
                //.xaxis()
                .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 80})
                .dimension(sicValueOrig)
                .group(sicValueGroupCountOrig)

                //.colors(d3.scale.category20())
                .colorAccessor(function(d){

                   if(d.key < 1000)
                     return "000";
                   else if (d.key > 1000 && d.key < 2000)
                     return "1000";
                   else if (d.key > 2000 && d.key < 3000)
                     return "2000";

                   //console.log(d.key);
                })
                 .colors(function(d){
                    return colorScale(d);
                })
                .keyAccessor(function (p) {
                  // console.log(p)
                   return p.key;
                })
                .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                   return p.value;
                })
                .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
                   return p.value;
                }) 
                .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200000]))
                .minRadiusWithLabel(5)
                .elasticY(true)
                .yAxisPadding(100)
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxisPadding(200)
                .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.10)
                .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
                .renderLabel(true)
                .renderTitle(true)
                .title(function (p) {
                  return "SIC number: "+p.key+"\nTotal Count: "+p.value;
                }).xAxis().tickValues([]);
        industryChart.yAxis().tickFormat(function (s) {
            return s + " filings";
        });


        dc.renderAll();
```

It would be a great help if any of you could point out what I am doing wrong and suggest a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at the [version 2.0 documentation for `chart.colors()`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colors__anchor) but using version 1.7 or below. In earlier versions, the function took a scale, not a function.

Unless you have a good reason, I think it's better form to pass the scale here, rather than a function calling the scale.

So instead of

```
            .colors(function(d){
                return colorScale(d);
            })
```

try

```
            .colors(colorScale)
```

That said, I think your code should work with dc.js 2.0, which was released early this year.

Comment: I tried changing the dc.js version to 2.1.6 and passed the scale instead of the function as suggested.  It finally works as the bubble chart now displays colors based on the colorAccessor logic. Thanks a lot for pointing these out!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!